# how to link google cloud virtual machine to a subdomain

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, subdomain, gcloud, client-library

I have a cloud virtual instance with a physical address say 244.168.0.221 . I also have a domain abc.com in google domains. how to  connect this IP to subdomain "first.abc.com" using google API client library ( node-JS client library ).ie How to create a A record using google node-JS Client library ?

Comment: can be done using http request like this                                                                        
POST /nic/update?hostname=subdomain.yourdomain.com&myip=1.2.3.4 HTTP/1.1
Host: domains.google.com
Authorization: Basic base64-encoded-auth-string User-Agent: Chrome/41.0 your_email@yourdomain.com

Comment: https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6147083?hl=en#zippy=%2Cuse-the-api-to-update-your-dynamic-dns-record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using google cloud domains
**Steps to follow**

1. Transfer your domain registration to google cloud domain.
   [transfer](https://cloud.google.com/domains/docs/domain-transfer-in)
2. Create zone in cloud DNS
   [create zone](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart/?hl=en)
3. Create A record pointing to the physical address of GCP virtual machine in the zone
   [create a "A" record](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/records?hl=en)

Now follow this sample, cloud DNS NodeJS Client library [nodejs client](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/dns/1.2.0/Zone.html#createChange)

Answer (score 1):

Google Domains does not provide a public API to create DNS Resource Records.

Answer (score 0):

Create a A record in your registrar that link your (sub)domains to your IP.

Comment: know it to do via console. my questions is how you do that in a google cloud node-JS client  library. how to create A record in google DNS via google domain API in default google domain name server